# Employee, Department and Units

Tags: mysql, database

I have these Requirements, the Company has Departments, and some Department has multiple Units.
Some Employees work on Department and others work on Units.

Employee

```
Name |  Dept |  Unit             
---- | ------| ---------
John | Micro | Bacteriology    
Dave | IT    |     --
```

Dept

```
 Name 
------ |
Micro  |
 IT    |
```

Unit

```
Name         |  Dept
------------ | -----
Bacteriology | Micro
```

How to design a database for the requirements.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The same way you have depicted in your post.

Have a table called `Dept`

```
Dept(Id PK, Name)
```

Have a table for units which will have a FK to `Dept`

```
Units(Id, Name, DeptId (FK))
```

Have a table for `Employee` which will also refer to `Dept` as well as `Units`

```
Employee (Id, Name, DeptId(FK), UnitId(FK))
```

Comment: I don't see how this links an employee to a unit, should his department have a unit.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your help, but some employees work on department without units,  and others work on units.

Comment: @ Tim 
Not all departments have Units

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, we can make a `JOIN` with `units` table on the `deptId` and get the unit name if any

Comment: @Rahul That won't work because a given department may have many units.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, perfect ... makes sense. Thanks for pointing